# adding a dropdown/select with multiple file upload using WebMatrix

Tags: webmatrix-2

I'm hoping someone can help with adding a select field in WebMatrix2. I want to be able to add folders inside App_data > UploadedFiles > folderA, foldeB etc that populates the select field with folderA, folderB and so forth.

I have followed the 'Working with Files in an ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Site' the code does work but it only show how to add multiple files to a specific directory(UploadedFiles). I'd like to be able to save files according to the dropdown.

here is what I have so far:

```
@using Microsoft.Web.Helpers;
 @{
var message = "";
if (IsPost) {
  var fileName = "";
  var fileSavePath = "";
  int numFiles = Request.Files.Count;
  int uploadedCount = 0;
  for(int i =0; i < numFiles; i++) {
      var uploadedFile = Request.Files[i];
      if (uploadedFile.ContentLength > 0) {
          fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
          fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/UploadedFiles/" +fileName);
          uploadedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
          uploadedCount++;
      }
   }
     Response.Redirect("videoList.cshtml");
 }
}
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
  <div>
 <h1>File Upload - Multiple-File Example</h1>
  @if (!IsPost) {
    @FileUpload.GetHtml(
        initialNumberOfFiles:2,
        allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:false,
        includeFormTag:false,
        addText:"Add another file",
        uploadText:"Upload")
    }  
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" />       
  </form>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you want to provide a dropdown per file upload? If so, I'd recommend not using the the FileUpload helper. Just use basic HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file1" />
<select name="folder1">
    <option>FolderA</option>
    <option>FolderB</option>
</select>
<br />
<input type="file" name="file2" />
<select name="folder2">
    <option>FolderA</option>
    <option>FolderB</option>
</select>
<input type="submit />
</form>
```

The first file will be in `Request.Files["file1"]` and the corresponding dropdown selection with be in `Request["folder1"]`

Comment: Thanks Mike - I'll keep that in mind. I eventually worked it out using the FileUpload helper. I wanted the dropdwon populating dynamically with any folder added to the directory. But if I need to provide a dropdown per upload I'll definitely use your solution.